# how to get value from api with flutter

Tags: api, flutter, dart, stream, response

I have fake Api

```
https://fakemyapi.com/api/fake?id=220e0e14-8c78-45e9-9ef0-6ca516fde5be
```

and I want to print some data, I used this code

```
var headers = {
  'Cookie': '__cfduid=d99061ead63f349023a08a33868eb7ef81619925287'
};
var request = http.Request('GET', Uri.parse('https://fakemyapi.com/api/fake?id=220e0e14-8c78-45e9-9ef0-6ca516fde5be'));

request.headers.addAll(headers);

http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
  print(await response.stream.bytesToString());
}
else {
  print(response.reasonPhrase);
}
```

and I get this response.
I/flutter (17790): {"first_ame":"Miguel","last_name":"Fay","photo":"https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/dhooyenga/128.jpg","email":"Keven.Cole@gmail.com","title":"Regional Functionality Developer","job_type":"Supervisor","telephone":["567.700.9452","1-701-720-0774 x9918","1-716-687-6317 x670"],"address":{"zip_code":"20909","street":"Myrtis Pines","city":"West Mekhifort","country":"Greece"},"friends":[{"first_name":"Carlie","last_name":"Kilback","email":"Erich_Emmerich90@gmail.com"},{"first_name":"Clarabelle","last_name":"Runolfsson","email":"Elise_Schroeder@gmail.com"}]}

so how to print the first name and zip code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got this solve by trying again and again,

```
    var headers = {
      'Cookie': '__cfduid=d99061ead63f349023a08a33868eb7ef81619925287'
    };
    var request = http.Request(
        'GET',
        Uri.parse(
            'https://fakemyapi.com/api/fake?id=220e0e14-8c78-45e9-9ef0-6ca516fde5be'));

    request.headers.addAll(headers);

    http.StreamedResponse response = await request.send();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      var item =
          JsonDecoder().convert("${await response.stream.bytesToString()}");
      print("item $item");
      print("first_ame ${item['first_ame']}");
      return item;
    } else {
      print(response.reasonPhrase);
    }
```